# Where should I put code that implements the answer to my question?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, best-practices, code

I asked a question and received an answer that I accepted as the best one.

The guy who gave that answer said that if I were to write the code he had suggested, he'd like to see it as he would find it helpful too.

The code I've written is about 50 lines long and I'd like to share it with him. Where should I put it?

The options I can think of are:

1. Edit my question to include the code. (Most visible, but seems a bit weird putting my own answer in the question.)
2. Add another answer. (Accepting it seems wrong as I've already accepted the help he gave me as the answer; not accepting it would make it less visible.)
3. Edit his answer to include the code. (I have enough rep to do this, but other users in this situation may not have.)

For reference, the question is [Trap the enter key, but not when choosing the browser's autocomplete suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648993/)

Answer (score 8):

Just add another answer, and accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: +1 - exactly what I was going to say

Comment: Also, comment on the other answer, so they get notice that the code is now available.